# What is the best way to have different Objects in a recycler view?

Tags: android, gson

My `recycler view` get a list of data from `youtube API` using `GSON` library. In one URL, the returned `JSON` is :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#playlist",
etag: ""tag/abc"",
id: "id",
```

Notice that the id field is a `String`

The problem is, the other URL return :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#searchResult",
etag: ""etag/abc"",
id: {
kind: "youtube#playlist",
playlistId: "id"
},
```

The id become a `Class`.

The simplest way is to create different `GSON` models and different `adapter` for the `recycler view`. However we will need to call `setAdapter` multiple time, which will impact the performance.

Do anyone have better workaround for this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: *However we will need to call setAdapter multiple time,* Why ?

Comment: @Blackbelt because i define my 'ArrayList<>' in the adapter...so i will need to create 2 different adapters

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create multiple `RecyclerView.Adapter`. 
RecyclerView and ListView can act the same using `@Override` `getItemViewType(int position)`.

See [documentation here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

**In Your adapter:**
1. `@Override` `getItemViewType(int position)`. 
    You will return a final static int representing your view type (like 1 or 0)
2. Inflate the correct view in `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` which as the viewType.
3. in your `onBindViewHolder` manage your object type.

**Extended** example for your adapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER = 1;

    private LinkedList<Message> mDataSet = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        // We assume we have the same ViewHolder, but you will prefer to use two different viewHolder as it make more sense
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message_footer, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Define here the rule to change the view type according the position and your data
        return (position == mDataSet.size()) ? VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER : VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Check the position or the instance of holder and change the view data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I define my `arraylist` in the adapter : `private ArrayList<Item> rows;`. What should i do?.

Comment: Sorry if i offense you. I understood the recycler view can have different views, but how about the different models (array list's object) i need to use? Because an array list can only represent 1 Object, in my case `ArrayList<Item>`

Comment: You can have to to collection of `List` or a `List<Object>`. Up to you to choose the right one, and you will need to check and cast the instance of the Object after in the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, it looks like a Youtube search result contains a list of Youtube Playlist items.  So I would just take the playlist items out of the search results and use those.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to not have two different objects, but have one object that is the interface that your `RecyclerView.Adapter` understands. Most lists have basic information, so there's no reason to couple the source of the information. So in this case,

```
public interface AdapterInterface {
   public String getTitle();
   public String getDescription();
}
```

Then, you can create any object that's backed by any kind of data you want and specify what kind of data is a "title" and a "description".

```
public class YoutubeObject1 implements AdapterInterface {
   private final class YoutubePlaylistObject mObject;

   public YoutubeObject1(YoutubePlalistObject object) {
      mObject = object;
   }

   @Override
   public String getTitle() {
      return mObject.getTitle();
   }

   @Override
   public String getDescription() {
      return mObject.getId();
   }
}
```

Then, for your RecyclerView.Adapter you just use the interface

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

   private final ArrayList<AdapterInterface> mItems;

   public MyAdapter() {
     mItems = new ArrayList<AdapterInterface>();
   }

   public void addItem(AdapterItem item) {
     mItems.add(item);
   }

   ... other methods....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry i dont understand your solution (i never create an interface before). I define my `arraylist` in the `adapter` : `private ArrayList<Item> rows;`. What should i do with your interface?

Comment: And sorry, i also dont understand this one : "Well, first, it looks like a Youtube search result contains a list of Youtube Playlist items. So I would just take the playlist items out of the search results and use those.". Sorry im a noob :)

Comment: Interfaces are contracts. So any object that implements an interface *must* implement the methods of the interface.  If the adapter only recognizes the interface, then you can put as type of object you want that implements the interface.  It doesn't matter what or where the information comes from as long as the title and description are Strings.

Comment: @BlazeTama  The items returned in the search results appear to be the same as the item returned by an individual playlist, but there is an array of them rather than the single item.